# Need help finding KML data for specific ZIP code

Tags: geocoding, kml, zipcode

I'm making a heat map using New Jersey ZIP codes, but the geometry information I'm using is incorrect for two ZIP codes. Does anyone know where I can go to get the KML information for these two specific ZIP codes? I've seen a lot of posts here on what resources to use for KML data, but they are very advanced and I have no idea how to mine the databases that other people on the forum have linked to.

Specifically, I need the KML ZIP code data for ZIP codes 08559 and 08757. The following is the flawed KML data I have for these ZIP codes:

08559:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-74.892528,40.414294,0.0 -74.967386,40.39857,0.0 -75.060361,40.420788,0.0 -75.064463,40.500774,0.0 -75.06583,40.517523,0.0 -75.068223,40.457705,0.0 -74.991314,40.481632,0.0 -74.88911,40.47001,0.0 -74.892528,40.414294,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

08757:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-74.190432,39.946002,0.0 -74.221537,39.932329,0.0 -74.322374,39.946002,0.0 -74.234185,40.008896,0.0 -74.26905,39.986678,0.0 -74.206839,39.952154,0.0 -74.19761,39.949762,0.0 -74.190432,39.946002,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

Comment: This is kind of a GIS question. It's the wrong place to ask ...

Answer (score 2):

## How to Create a Region Map with Multiple Zip Codes

1. Download KML file containing all US zip codes from [census.gov](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/kml/kml_zcta.html). The most current file on this site is: http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2015/kml/cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k.zip. If this link is broken search Google for [site:census.gov KML ZIP](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acensus.gov+KML+ZIP). Another option: https://www.filosophy.org/post/17/zipcodes_in_kml/

2. Open this huge (175MB) text file in a plaintext editor and search for the zip code you want and copy the `<Polygon>` section. Here is the result when searching for `>94117`:

   ```xml
   <Placemark id="cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k.kml">
   <name>&lt;at&gt;&lt;openparen&gt;&lt;closeparen&gt;</name>
   <visibility>1</visibility>
   <description><![CDATA[<center><table><tr><th colspan='2' align='center'><em>Attributes</em></th></tr><tr bgcolor="#E3E3F3">
   <th>ZCTA5CE10</th>
   <td>94117</td>
   </tr><tr bgcolor="">
   <th>AFFGEOID10</th>
   <td>8600000US94117</td>
   </tr><tr bgcolor="#E3E3F3">
   <th>GEOID10</th>
   <td>94117</td>
   </tr><tr bgcolor="">
   <th>ALAND10</th>
   <td>4373059</td>
   </tr><tr bgcolor="#E3E3F3">
   <th>AWATER10</th>
   <td>1625</td>
   </tr></table></center>]]></description>
   <LookAt>
   <longitude>-102</longitude>
   <latitude>38.5</latitude>
   <range>7000000</range>
   <tilt>10</tilt>
   <heading>0</heading>
   </LookAt>
   <styleUrl>#KMLStyler</styleUrl>
   <ExtendedData>
   <SchemaData schemaUrl="#kml_schema_ft_cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k">
   <SimpleData name="ZCTA5CE10">94117</SimpleData>
   <SimpleData name="AFFGEOID10">8600000US94117</SimpleData>
   <SimpleData name="GEOID10">94117</SimpleData>
   <SimpleData name="ALAND10">4373059</SimpleData>
   <SimpleData name="AWATER10">1625</SimpleData>
   </SchemaData>
   </ExtendedData>
   <Polygon>
   <extrude>0</extrude>
   <tessellate>1</tessellate>
   <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
   <outerBoundaryIs>
   <LinearRing>
   <coordinates>-122.477297,37.766069,0 -122.477379,37.765482,0 -122.458405,37.76616,0 -122.45779,37.766015,0 -122.457536,37.763566,0 -122.455999,37.763904,0 -122.456994,37.761842,0 -122.459173,37.761912,0 -122.455944,37.760239,0 -122.456603,37.759235,0 -122.454002,37.758785,0 -122.451817,37.759453,0 -122.447682,37.75919,0 -122.446783,37.761781,0 -122.445309,37.76188,0 -122.442915,37.763648,0 -122.443347,37.765333,0 -122.441242,37.765271,0 -122.4382,37.767159,0 -122.435624,37.767328,0 -122.435794,37.769058,0 -122.429128,37.769456,0 -122.428426,37.770452,0 -122.429178,37.774181,0 -122.429929,37.777909,0 -122.430115,37.778842,0 -122.444967,37.776958,0 -122.44478,37.776017,0 -122.446471,37.775802,0 -122.446846,37.777669,0 -122.453188,37.776853,0 -122.45281,37.774995,0 -122.463749,37.773624,0 -122.464611,37.77244,0 -122.459162,37.771314,0 -122.459901,37.770442,0 -122.464402,37.769669,0 -122.467004,37.768013,0 -122.469758,37.769209,0 -122.472245,37.76861,0 -122.473124,37.767116,0 -122.477297,37.766069,0 </coordinates>
   </LinearRing>
   </outerBoundaryIs>
   </Polygon>
   </Placemark>
   ```

3. Create a clean KML file and move the `<Polygon>` to this file. Below is an example of a KML file (`service-delivery-area.kml`) with two zip code polygons. Google has a great [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference).

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
     <Document>
       <name>Service Delivery Area</name>
       <open>0</open>
       <Placemark>
         <name>94117</name>
         <Polygon>
           <outerBoundaryIs>
             <LinearRing>
               <coordinates>
                 -122.477297,37.766069,0 -122.477379,37.765482,0 -122.458405,37.76616,0 -122.45779,37.766015,0 -122.457536,37.763566,0 -122.455999,37.763904,0 -122.456994,37.761842,0 -122.459173,37.761912,0 -122.455944,37.760239,0 -122.456603,37.759235,0 -122.454002,37.758785,0 -122.451817,37.759453,0 -122.447682,37.75919,0 -122.446783,37.761781,0 -122.445309,37.76188,0 -122.442915,37.763648,0 -122.443347,37.765333,0 -122.441242,37.765271,0 -122.4382,37.767159,0 -122.435624,37.767328,0 -122.435794,37.769058,0 -122.429128,37.769456,0 -122.428426,37.770452,0 -122.429178,37.774181,0 -122.429929,37.777909,0 -122.430115,37.778842,0 -122.444967,37.776958,0 -122.44478,37.776017,0 -122.446471,37.775802,0 -122.446846,37.777669,0 -122.453188,37.776853,0 -122.45281,37.774995,0 -122.463749,37.773624,0 -122.464611,37.77244,0 -122.459162,37.771314,0 -122.459901,37.770442,0 -122.464402,37.769669,0 -122.467004,37.768013,0 -122.469758,37.769209,0 -122.472245,37.76861,0 -122.473124,37.767116,0 -122.477297,37.766069,0
               </coordinates>
             </LinearRing>
           </outerBoundaryIs>
         </Polygon>
       </Placemark>
       <Placemark>
         <name>94102</name>
         <Polygon>
           <outerBoundaryIs>
             <LinearRing>
               <coordinates>
                 -122.429929,37.777909,0 -122.429178,37.774181,0 -122.428426,37.770452,0 -122.42822,37.769441,0 -122.426402,37.769596,0 -122.419334,37.77521,0 -122.419219,37.775316,0 -122.418704,37.775645,0 -122.404743,37.786778,0 -122.406399,37.786615,0 -122.406771,37.788499,0 -122.408595,37.789226,0 -122.411886,37.788808,0 -122.414807,37.78652,0 -122.414242,37.783724,0 -122.419182,37.783101,0 -122.420689,37.781955,0 -122.420906,37.782883,0 -122.422287,37.781752,0 -122.424108,37.782477,0 -122.427396,37.782057,0 -122.426829,37.779258,0 -122.429929,37.777909,0
               </coordinates>
             </LinearRing>
           </outerBoundaryIs>
         </Polygon>
       </Placemark>
     </Document>
   </kml>
   ```

4. Go to https://www.google.com/mymaps/ and create a new map. Click "Add new layer", then click "Import", and upload your KML file. If the polygons are incorrect, you can edit the polygons on the map.

5. Your map should have a result like this: https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1zop5GMD1b2afmOvObQIi7YvF1d4

Answer (score 2):

There's a directory where you can easily search and download Census KML boundary files for any zip code, county or state.

**Individual zip code KML**
Here are links to KML files for the 2 zip codes you mentioned:
https://census.simplecrew.com/us/zip-codes/08559
https://census.simplecrew.com/us/zip-codes/08757

**All zip codes by county KML**
You could even download a single KML file for all zip codes by county. For example, your 2 zip codes are in Hunterdon and Ocean counties:
https://census.simplecrew.com/us/states/nj/counties/hunterdon/zip-codes
https://census.simplecrew.com/us/states/nj/counties/ocean/zip-codes

**All zip codes by state KML**
Also, instead of creating a map of all zip codes in NJ yourself, you could just download a single KML file here:
https://census.simplecrew.com/us/states/nj/zip-codes

Answer (score 1):

For just US zip codes there is data available from the US Census:
http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/z52000.html#ascii

Download ASCII dataset for New Jersey or any of other 50 states.

You can lookup the index to your zip codes in the small file (e.g. zt34_d00a.dat)

```
 317
 "08559"
 "08559"
 "Z5"
 "5-Digit ZCTA"
```

Then find the matching lon/lat coordinate list in the large file.

```
317      -0.749719256389896E+02       0.404391641604938E+02
      -0.750611840000000E+02       0.404766960000000E+02
      -0.750607720000000E+02       0.404766880000000E+02
      -0.750620530000000E+02       0.404692640000000E+02
      -0.750637010000000E+02       0.404652440000000E+02
...
      -0.750622670000000E+02       0.404709200000000E+02
      -0.750611840000000E+02       0.404766960000000E+02
END
```

The first value is longitude and second value is latitude both in decimal degrees.

NOTE some of the points may be out of order (or erroneous) so you may have to clean it up after you convert to KML. One handy tool to help debug the points and remove the bad points is a [KML Number-the-points tool](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/numbers.html) that generates KML Placemarks each with number label corresponding to each point in a line or polygon given some KML as input. Useful if have long list of points and need to easily identify them.